# How to read and understand json file

Tags: json, dynamic, getjson

I'm trying to understand who to read this format of json but I can't I don't know what it map to

I don't know what is "number:number:'text'" equal to m is it array of objects or what definitely  it is ?

all what I figured is that we have some variables at the object a:4

```
a: 1: {
s: 2: "r1";
a: 4: {
    s: 12: "number_votes";
    i: 2;
    s: 12: "total_points";
    i: 6;
    s: 7: "dec_avg";
    d: 3;
    s: 9: "whole_avg";
    d: 3;
  }
}
```

Hope some one could make it readable for me .
As it's supposed to make such a static structure dynamic and call each value from the database !

I know the common structure for json file like

```
{"employees":[
     {"firstName":"Mustafa", "lastName":"Elnagar"}, 

]}
```

Comment: this format is used to make 5 star rating system http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php--net-11541

Comment: The first snippet you posted is not valid JSON, but a an array or object serialized by PHP using `serialize()`.

Comment: thanks alot "F21" for your help & time , he already use it at the tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php--net-11541   to read the values from it and pass to the stars , So should I create equivilant one with pure php "as the result come from the db " and then unserialize it ?

Comment: If you need to pass the data to the client (using AJAX for example), then encode the data as JSON so that the client can parse it.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet is not JSON, but an object or array serialized by PHP using `serialize()`.

First, let's decode it. Note that the serialized string should not have any whitespaces, because it breaks the unserialization:

```
<?php
$serialized = 'a:1:{s:2:"r1";a:4:{s:12:"number_votes";i:2;s:12:"total_points";i:6;s:7:"dec_avg";d:3;s:9:"whole_avg";d:3;}}';

var_dump(unserialize($serialized));
```

This is our output:

```
array (size=1)
  'r1' => 
    array (size=4)
      'number_votes' => int 2
      'total_points' => int 6
      'dec_avg' => float 3
      'whole_avg' => float 3
```

If you want to pass the above back to the client to be used by your javascript code, encode it as JSON:

```
<?php
$serialized = 'a:1:{s:2:"r1";a:4:{s:12:"number_votes";i:2;s:12:"total_points";i:6;s:7:"dec_avg";d:3;s:9:"whole_avg";d:3;}}';

$unserialized = unserialize($serialized);

var_dump(json_encode($unserialized, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

This results in valid JSON:

```
{
    "r1": {
        "number_votes": 2,
        "total_points": 6,
        "dec_avg": 3,
        "whole_avg": 3
    }
}
```

You probably want to remove the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag in production as that's just to make the JSON easier to read.

Comment: thanks a lot F21 , you made my day , valuable information and functions I got , I will back to my code and run it!